# Warning: modified in the future

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting the warning

```
Warning: sendmailpm.jsp modified in the future.
```

What does this mean?

Comment: That the LHC is up and running, and we're all about to die :(

Comment: I think you should see, if your tomcat timezone is set correctly. This is done in setenv.(bat|sh) with something like this:                 "-Duser.timezone=Europe/BERLIN". http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/15954-alphabetic-java-time-zones-continent-ocean-city-format has a list of java timezones.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You aren't allowed to modify anything in the past if doing so might change the future. You might cause a temporal paradox, which could corrupt the time stream and cause our entire reality to cease to exist.

Please do not modify that file.

Comment: I am having this same error. For real. This answer is not helpful at all...  BTW, if you guys find this funny, you will have a field day with Java 8's [Duration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. It can become [negative](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#isNegative--)! So I will post this comment in minus 5 seconds.

Answer (score 18):

JSP files are compiled. Many servers also allow you to replace the files on a running server. It then compares the timestamp of the compiled source and the timestamp of the jsp file to determine if it needs to recompile.

If the file is dated in the future, the jsp file will always be newer than the class. This gives you a warning.

Check the timestamp on the file. Perhaps someone created it on a computer with an incorrect clock, and now it appears to be "created in the future".  Or perhaps the server has the incorrect date (check timezone settings).

Are there remote file servers involved? Clock drift between a web server and a file server can cause this error too.

To diagnose this further, you'd have to give us some hints - what jsp server, what OS, what filesystem?

Answer (score 6):

During an Ant build, this warning can be output during a  task.

```
[copy] Warning: foo\bar.txt modified in the future.
```

Ant's `<copy>` task by default won't copy files if the destination files are newer than the source. This saves much time and disk I/O. However you can override this behavior with the option `<copy overwrite="true">`. This tells Ant that you know what you're doing; overwrite the destination files regardless of their modification date. This will also suppress the warning.

Comment: Problems like this with Ant can be from issues with FAT/ FAT32 filesystem's lack of timestamp precision, on Windows use NTFS instead, see details in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If your code is residing on a FAT/FAT32 partition or ZIP file, this can be caused by the lack of precision in the FAT/ZIP filesystem's timestamping, which is 2 seconds (afaik). This can cause compiler / build tool output to be saved with a time slightly in the future, so that when the next build/deployment step (can be internal to a JSP container) is executed, the file will appear to be from the future and the warning is produced. Try using a different file system, e.g. NTFS on DOS/Windows boxes.

I had the same warning message from Apache Ant when trying to do a Java build on a FAT32 TrueCrypt partition. After ruling out other causes (timezone difference, clock off etc), I eventually found a hint on this, changed to an NTFS TrueCrypt partition and the warning disappeared.

Comment: Thank you, I realize this is an odd error message and most people couldn't help themselves, but this is what I needed.

Comment: Don't forget that ZIP files internally use the same precision as FAT which is where the warning can come from too.

Comment: Thanks @PeterQuiring! I have added ZIP filesystems to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Someone probably modified the file, then changed the time on the server. Try checking to see what time your box is set to and make sure it's correct. If it is, you can probably ignore that warning without any side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Check whether system time is correct or not. If not sync it with Standard time for your zone. Then run your build file.

Answer (score 2):

JSPs are compiled on-the-fly to servlets. The servlet container compares the "last modified" dates of both to see if the JSP has been changed and the servlet needs to be updated. A "last modified" date in the future indicates that something is wrong with the system clock, which is relevant because it could disrupt the abovementioned mechanism, leading to servlets that are not updated.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, The time of the system is not current on which you are running the build file

Answer (score 1):

If the java file that you are compiling has a time stamp that is beyond the current time of the system on which you are compiling...you will see this warning.
I modified the file on one machine and put it on another and tried compiling and came across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. The solution was: I changed the date and time on the build machine, so that it was in sync with the date and time on machine which the files were copied to.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a jar file that you are trying to install at remote server. It might happen that remote server timestamp is not matching with your time zone. If your timezone is couple of hour ahead than the remote server then you might get this issue.
I also tried out one more trick..
When you create a JAR file, then go to system time and set a date couple of months back and try installing the JAR, you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error too, but after reading some answers above i realized that is was due to the change i've done in the computer to some days ahead because of the test of a functionality that requires date manipulation.

Here is what happened:

1 - To perform Unit Test of a new implemented functionality i had to set the computer date to 4 days in the future.

2 - When i performed the test the compiler compiled the class automatically, as expected.

3 - Therefore when i was trying to rebuild the project the IDE detected that the file was (ironically) created in the future. (LoL - that's why i love Java you can even code in the future.).

So +1 @jmanning2k.

I hope it can help somebody facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That warning appear to me too, it was because a previously changed the time in my computer to fix it because it was like 20 minutes ahead of the actual time