# Ant Compile Issue

Tags: java, ant

I compile one java program with today date, then I changed the system date to yesterday and modified the java file. Now it won't compile. Still i have class with created date today.

```
<project name="SampleTest">
<target name="compile">
    <javac srcdir="${user.dir}" destdir="${user.dir}"/>
</target>
<target name="run">
    <java classname="TestSample" classpath="."/>
</target>
</project>
```

In this i got warning message

compile:
    [javac] Warning: TestSample.class modified in the future.
Apache Ant version 1.6.2 compiled on August 5 2004

Answer (score 0):

[Warning: modified in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001662/warning-modified-in-the-future) probably contains some kind of explanation you're looking for.  There are multiple thoughts on this behavior such as:

"Problems like this with Ant can be from issues with FAT/ FAT32 filesystem's lack of timestamp precision, on Windows use NTFS instead, see details in my answer."

Or:

"JSP files are compiled. Many servers also allow you to replace the files on a running server. It then compares the timestamp of the compiled source and the timestamp of the jsp file to determine if it needs to recompile.

If the file is dated in the future, the jsp file will always be newer than the class. This gives you a warning.

Check the timestamp on the file. Perhaps someone created it on a computer with an incorrect clock, and now it appears to be "created in the future". Or perhaps the server has the incorrect date (check timezone settings).

Are there remote file servers involved? Clock drift between a web server and a file server can cause this error too."

But my question I pose to you is what exactly are you trying to accomplish in doing this?  I'm sure this was implemented as some kind of failsafe behavior.  If that's the case, then it's definitely working.

You could always consider having Ant delete the .class file first.

Comment: I faced this problem one time when my system date in wrong. So try to test this case. But why the same scenario work fine with normal java compilation through console.

Comment: It's Ant that's causing the issue.  The Java compiler seems to not care about the timestamp of the file, but Ant does.